# Flutter reactive ble uart problem with Android 8 (Updated)

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, reactive, uart

I updated the *flutter reactive ble uart demo app*. The code can be found [on github](https://github.com/SietseAchterop/My_BLE_UART).
I now use recent flutter (3.3.6), android studio (2021.3.1) and libraries, and it seems to work fine, but...

On my Samsung tablet (Android 10) it works fine, but my smartphone Samsung S7 (Android 8) has a problem.
Often, after connecting, there is a immediate disconnect. This often with one of the following error messages (see main.dart line 167):

> GenericFailure(code:CharacteristicValueUpdateError.unknown, message: "Disconnected from MAC='XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with status 19 (GATT_CONN_TERMINATE_PEER_USER")E7:05...  ($id)

> GenericFailure(code:CharacteristicValueUpdateError.unknown, essage: "Cannot write client characteristic config descriptor (code 3) with characteristic UUID 6e4000....")E7:05...

What also is strange there seems to be a kind of switch, either there is no error for some time of this error occurs every time.
What could be the problem and why is it only happening with Android 8?

Regards Sietse.

PS. The peripheral is an Arduino nano33ble with the Nordic UART example program. It is working fine with the nRF Toolbox on Android and on Linux, so I presume that side is OK.

### Update

I found out that when the error occurs it can be resolved (for some time) by removing the bonding/pairing of the device.
(I have to confess that I added bonding/pairing to the Nordic UART example)